# Except replacement in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have to write some code in mysql but mostly I write in MS SQL and here is problem, in MS SQL I can use EXCEPT and everything is fine for me. But in MySQL there is not that simple, I tried with NOT IN and NOT EXISTS but it didn't give me same output. My MS SQL code is:

```
SELECT P.IDRoom, R.IDRoom, R.DateB, R.DataE
FROM Room P LEFT JOIN Reservation R ON P.IDRoom = R.IDRoom
JOIN Hotel H ON P.IDHotelu = H.IDHotelu
WHERE P.NumberOfBeds = 2 AND H.IDHotelu = 2 
EXCEPT
SELECT P.IDRoom, R.IDRoom, R.DateB, R.DataE
FROM Room P JOIN Reservation R ON P.IDRoom = R.IDRoom
WHERE '2017-12-10' BETWEEN DataB AND DataE;
```

Like u can see I look for hotel who have 2 beds and hotel id is 2. but I don't want to see rooms who are already booked so I use except and look for booked rooms... but it's easy in MS SQL, in MySQL nothing work for me -_-. Any ideas?

Comment: [`NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) is the right direction.  Please post your MySQL query so we can look at it, as the SQL Server query is working and has no impact on they MySQL results.

Comment: NOT EXISTS is indeed the right direction  with a DISTINCT... `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM ... NOT EXISTS (.... )` ... "EXCEPT
Returns any distinct values from the query to the left of the EXCEPT operator that are not also returned from the right query. " source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql

Comment: I tried with SELECT P.IDRoom, R.IDRoom, R.DateB, R.DataE
FROM Room P LEFT JOIN Reservation R ON P.IDRoom = R.IDRoom
JOIN Hotel H ON P.IDHotelu = H.IDHotelu
WHERE P.NumberOfBeds = 2 AND H.IDHotelu = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT DateB, DateE FROM Reservation WHERE '2017-12-10' BETWEEN DateB And DateE);

When I tried with different date who is not booked it works... show me all rows but when i try to check if it will exclude those who are already booked everything dissapear.... so there is error in my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a sub-query and join the outer table on to it with a LEFT JOIN. This then lets you put a WHERE column IS NULL.

```
SELECT
    P.IDRoom
   ,R.IDRoom
   ,R.DateB
   ,R.DataE
FROM
    Room P
    LEFT JOIN Reservation R ON P.IDRoom = R.IDRoom
    INNER JOIN Hotel H ON P.IDHotelu = H.IDHotelu
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        P.IDRoom AS IDRoom1
        ,R.IDRoom AS IDRoom2
        ,R.DateB
        ,R.DataE
    FROM
        Room P
        JOIN Reservation R ON P.IDRoom = R.IDRoom
    WHERE
        '2017-12-10' BETWEEN DataB AND DataE
) AS e ON  P.IDRoom = e.IDRoom1 AND R.IDRoom = e.IDRoom2 AND R.DateB = e.DateB AND R.DataE = R.DataE
WHERE
    P.NumberOfBeds = 2 AND H.IDHotelu = 2 
    AND e.IDRoom1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I just wonder where was my logic mistake but I will analyze this code firstly

Comment: MySQL doesn't have the EXCEPT function. So instead, you just LEFT JOIN on your sub-query and ask for any rows that don't have a matching record in the sub-query (or IS NULL).

Answer (score 0):

The query below should behave like `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT P.IDRoom, R.IDRoom, R.DateB, R.DataE
FROM Room P 
LEFT JOIN Reservation R ON P.IDRoom = R.IDRoom
JOIN Hotel H ON P.IDHotelu = H.IDHotelu
WHERE P.NumberOfBeds = 2 AND H.IDHotelu = 2 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Room i_P 
        JOIN Reservation i_R ON i_P.IDRoom = i_R.IDRoom
        WHERE '2017-12-10' BETWEEN DataB AND DataE
            AND i_P.IDRoom = P.IDRoom
    )
```